# How do you handle multiple feed URLs in a migration?

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a drupal migration that also uses migrate plus from a feed URL that can be queried. For example the migration can work for a single response from the feed at

```
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http    
  data_parser_plugin: xml   
  urls: http://myfeed.com/newsfeed/get.php?id=123456
```

I would like to migrate content at 123456 and then 123457, then 123458.  How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to list any URLs that should be fetched:

```
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http    
  data_parser_plugin: xml   
  urls:
    - http://myfeed.com/newsfeed/get.php?id=123456
    - http://myfeed.com/newsfeed/get.php?id=123457
    - http://myfeed.com/newsfeed/get.php?id=123458
```

The Url plugin in migrate_plus converts single url values into an array by default: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_plus/blob/HEAD/src/Plugin/migrate/source/Url.php#L34

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to migrate to this 3 ids, just create 3 different migrations for each URL.

If the IDs are dinamic I will copy&paste [my own solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/256360/22808):

To solve this I had to create a source plugin that for each row calls a new data parse plugin with the URL for this row.

Here is the plugin:

```
/**
*
* @MigrateSource(
*   id = "url_per_row"
* )
*/
class UrlPerRow extends Url {

protected $dataNewParserPlugin;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, MigrationInterface $migration) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $migration);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
    $prepare_row = parent::prepareRow($row);

    if (!$row->getIdMap() || $row->needsUpdate() || $this->aboveHighwater($row) || $this->rowChanged($row)) {
      $item_info_settings = $row->getSourceProperty('item_info');
      if (!empty($item_info_settings)) {
        $this->getItemData($row, $item_info_settings);
      }
    }

    return $prepare_row;
  }

  protected function getItemData(Row &$row, $settings) {
    $new_url = str_replace($settings['token'], $row->getSourceProperty($settings['token_replace']), $settings['url']);

    $this->getNewDataParserPlugin($new_url, $settings['item_selector'],     $row->getSource());
    $this->dataNewParserPlugin->rewind();
    $xml_data = $this->dataNewParserPlugin->current();
    if (!empty($xml_data)) {
      $fields = $row->getSourceProperty('fields');
      foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (!empty($field['item_info']) && !empty($xml_data[$field['name']])) {
          $row->setSourceProperty($field['name'], $xml_data[$field['name']]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  protected function getNewDataParserPlugin($url, $item_selector, $settings) {
    $settings['urls'] = [$url];
    $settings['item_selector'] = $item_selector;

    $this->dataNewParserPlugin = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.migrate_plus.data_parser')
      ->createInstance($settings['data_parser_plugin'], $settings);

    return $this->dataNewParserPlugin;
  }

}
```

Then I put some info in the migration .yml definition:

```
source:
  plugin: url_per_row
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  headers:
    Accept: application/xml
  data_parser_plugin: simple_xml
  urls: https://myws.com
  item_selector: /ResultWeb/data
  item_info:
    url: https://myws.com/[id]
    token: '[id]'
    token_replace: id
    item_selector: /ResultWeb/data
```

Notice that the `id` from `token_replace` is a field with name *id*. You can use other field.

Also, for every field where is needt to rereive information from the specified URL I put a `item_info: true` element.

```
-
  name: myfield
  label: 'My Field'
  selector: fields/field/my
  item_info: true
```