# Migrate multiple migrations into same node

Tags: 8, migrations

I need to do a migration from multiple endpoints into the same node. All endpoints provide the full list of rows/nodes, but their data need to be mapped into different fields of the same node and into different translations (so not similar to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254091/how-to-migrate-content-using-a-web-service-with-multiple-calls), where one endpoint is the complete list and the second is the single row data).

Here is what I've got so far:

First migration, create the nodes in default language

```
id: kognitiv_rooms_base
label: Rooms Step 1 (room data in german and available rates)
migration_group: kognitiv
migration_tags:
  - rooms
  - masterdata
status: true

source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls: https://www.example.com/rooms_endpoint_one.json?lang=de
  item_selector: /result/rooms
  track_changes: true
  fields:
    -
      name: code
      label: 'Kognitiv room code'
      selector: code
    -
      name: title
      label: 'Room name'
      selector: title
    -
      name: description
      label: 'Room description'
      selector: description
    -
      name: min_occupancy
      label: 'Minimum room occupancy'
      selector: min_occupancy
    -
      name: std_occupancy
      label: 'Standard room occupancy'
      selector: std_occupancy
    -
      name: max_occupancy
      label: 'Maximum room occupancy'
      selector: max_occupancy
  ids:
    code:
      type: string

destination:
  plugin: entity:node

process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: room
  title: title
  langcode:
     plugin: default_value
     default_value: de
  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  sticky:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
  promote:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
  short_description: description
  long_description: description
  room_min_occupancy: min_occupancy
  room_std_occupancy: std_occupancy
  room_max_occupancy: max_occupancy
  remote_datasource:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: kognitiv
  remote_id: code

dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - kognitiv_importer
```

Second migration, fill additional fields in existing nodes

```
id: kognitiv_rooms_ammenities
label: Rooms Step 2 (ammenities and room size)
migration_group: kognitiv
migration_tags:
  - rooms
  - masterdata
status: true

source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls: https://www.example.com/rooms_endpoint_two.json
  item_selector: /facility/rooms
  track_changes: true
  fields:
    -
      name: code
      label: 'Kognitiv room code'
      selector: code
    -
      name: size
      label: 'Room size'
      selector: /types/0/size
  ids:
    code:
      type: string

destination:
  plugin: entity:node

process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: room
  nid:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: kognitiv_rooms_base
    source: code
  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  roomsize: size

migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - kognitiv_rooms_base

dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - kognitiv_importer
```

Third migration, translate the nodes

```
id: kognitiv_rooms_en
label: Rooms Step 3 (english translation)
migration_group: kognitiv
migration_tags:
  - rooms
  - masterdata
  - english
status: true

source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls: https://www.example.com/rooms_endpoint_one.json?lang=en
  item_selector: /result/rooms
  track_changes: true
  fields:
    -
      name: code
      label: 'Kognitiv room code'
      selector: code
    -
      name: title
      label: 'Room name'
      selector: title
    -
      name: description
      label: 'Room description'
      selector: description
  ids:
    code:
      type: string

destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  translations: true

process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: room
  langcode:
     plugin: default_value
     default_value: en
  content_translation_source:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: de
  nid:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    source: code
    migration: kognitiv_rooms_base
  title: title
  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  short_description: description
  long_description: description

migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - kognitiv_rooms_base
    - kognitiv_rooms_ammenities

dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - kognitiv_importer
```

I've got the idea with setting `nid` with `migrate_lookup` from [those](https://www.liip.ch/en/blog/drupal-8-multilingual-content) [examples](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229750/how-to-migrate-multilingual-image-alt-fields-from-csv/229874), using it for translations.

My problem is that only the first migration works. Both the 2nd and 3rd migration fail because of a  `"Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000130' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {node} (nid, vid, type, uuid, langcode)..."`. The `nid` value is correct, but I guess it should be an `update` instead of an `insert`.

How can I force Migrate to update an existing node? The 2nd query should update the node in the same language, the 3rd query should add/update the english translation of the  node.

I'm on Drupal 8.4, using Migrate Plus 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above works, including updating existing nodes in the same language and adding/updating translations. After installing the module on a fresh site, everything worked. Obviously during the numerous iterations of developing, uninstalling and reinstalling, some invisible old data/cache/whatever was left in a rollback run and caused the error.